# Difference between Spring Kafka and Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

If I want to send messages to Kafka or consume messages from Kafka. Would you recommend using Spring Kafka library or just using Kafka Java API.

In Spring they provide a lot of annotations which seems more magics when having some runtime error.

Can someone differentiate between Spring Kafka and Kafka.

Comment: Probably the decision you’ll always have to make. In general all integrations of a library or service into spring(-boot) offer some great comfort but if something doesn’t work as desired is harder to debug/understand than a homebrew solution. I can’t say anything about spring-kafka in particular but I’d personally always use the official integrations with spring. It’s easier to find resources/help and bugs, that a homebrew solution will have, have probably already been fixed.

Comment: @dpr can you please help me to provide any additional features provided by spring kafka